# Problemas de posicionamiento de un menú creado con Elementor de WordPress

Tags: wordpress, navbar, menu, elementor, posicionamiento

Tengo un menú creado en WordPress con Elementor el cual se despliega a todo el ancho, pero no consigo que al desplegarse no tape cierta zona del header, aquí muestro imágenes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenté darle margen y relleno al menú de navegación y esto no funciona, y agregándole distancia al desplegable hace que solo funcione en ese tamaño de pantalla en el que lo visualizo, en otros tamaños se despega o se sube más.

Alguien sabe cómo puedo solucionar esto? Yo quiero que el menú desplegable se muestre siempre pegado debajo de la sección en la que se encuentra el header sin taparlo o que se aleje dejando ver el fondo; agradezco cualquier tipo de ayuda o sugerencia al respecto

Comment: Intenta crear el menú desde cero sin usar wordpress, solo html y css

Comment: @Xedrian gracias pero tengo que hacer la web en WordPress